How to bundle a Create React App into a single embed.js file for embedding in any website?
I'm working on a React app using Vite and I want to create a single embed.js file that I can include in any website to load my widget. The embed.js file should contain both the JavaScript and CSS. I am using the vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js plugin to inject CSS via JavaScript.
What I have tried:
screenshot is attached,

where i tried with this,


import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from 'vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    cssInjectedByJsPlugin()
  ]
});




now i have single js file in which there is a css and js code, but i want to make the embed-able js file where there  will be root html div too i think ? correct me as well,

were you succesfull at this ?

yes, i have already solved this

that’s great, do you mind sharing some code samples or a link to GitHub repository, I need this badly myself

@AlbertDugba
i found solution by trying this on the vite react app, where i am using the tailwind css and then make a build with minifed version of the JS file with the tailwind css classes,
see my vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from "vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    cssInjectedByJsPlugin({
      relativeCSSInjection: true,
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: { output: { manualChunks: undefined } },
    minify: true,
  },
  server: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3000,
  },
});

